# sklearn linear regression for large data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Does `sklearn.LinearRegression` support online/incremental learning?

I have 100 groups of data, and I am trying to implement them altogether. For each group, there are over 10000 instances and ~ 10 features, so it will lead to memory error with sklearn if I construct a huge matrix (10^6 by 10). It will be nice if I can update the regressor each time with batch samples of new group.

I found [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81740/recursive-online-regularised-least-squares-algorithm) relevant, but the accepted solution works for online learning with single new data (only one instance) rather than batch samples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at **`linear_model.SGDRegressor`**, it learns a a linear model using stochastic gradient.

In general, sklearn has many models that admit "`partial_fit`", they are all pretty useful on medium to large datasets that don't fit in the RAM.

Comment: Thank you caoy. It's helpful. But the input for sgdregressor is exactly the same as ordinary linear regressor (I still need the large datasets well prepared)?

Comment: @ChuNan, no you do not need to form the large datasets. Take a look at the example code: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#example-applications-plot-out-of-core-classification-py

Comment: @ChuNan, in particular, look at how chunks of data are constructed on the fly inside the generator function "iter_minibatches". If you are not familiar with the notion of python generator, take a look at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Not all algorithms can learn incrementally, without seeing all of the instances at once that is. That said, all estimators implementing the `partial_fit` API are candidates for the mini-batch learning, also known as "online learning".

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) is an article that goes over scaling strategies for incremental learning. For your purposes, have a look at the [`sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor) class. It is *truly* online so the memory and convergence rate are not affected by the batch size.

Comment: You're welcome. No, you do not need to contruct the entire matrix. It is done in the class via a `yield` generator.

Comment: Is the online learning capability the main difference between SGDRegressor and LinearRegression?

Comment: One more difference between SGDRegressor and LinearRegression: The former uses 'Stochastic gradient descent' for optimization of the loss function and the later works on a closed-form solution (such as the Normal Equation method).
For a large number of predictors, LinearRegression() becomes too slow. In that case, either you can use  SGDRegressor or change the solver in LinearRegression.